# Is there a defrost drain in my Samsung freezer? I cannot find one. This is a model RT18M6213

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

My Samsung refrigerator drips water from the freezer into the refrigerator. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You normally cannot find the drain hole in the freezer compartment unless you remove the inside back panel of the freezer. You should be able to see where the drain tube ends by looking inside the rear panel at the rear bottom of the refrig. From there, the water drips into a removable pan and evaporates.
The drain tube can become clogged and cause the defrost water to build up in the freezer and then leak into the lower portion of the refrig during the defrost cycle. If you remove the back panel of the freezer you will see a lot of ice build up if the drain is clogged. You'll have to let the ice all melt and clean out the drain all the way to the bottom with a long wire, tube, etc.